# unable to update in gridview when require validation occur in textbox

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview, updatecommand

I want to modify items in gridview by update command but in same page i have also a textbox with required validation.

i'm unable to update in gridview when require validation occur in textbox Control
[image]

And Source Code here...

```
 <div class="row">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click"
        ValidationGroup="btn" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Reset" OnClick="Button2_Click"
        CausesValidation="False" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Show" CausesValidation="False"
        OnClick="Button3_Click" />
</div>
</form> </div> </div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table-hover table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Loc" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Loc" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mycon %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [location]" DeleteCommand="Delete From Location Where Id=@id"
    UpdateCommand="update  location set loc=@loc where id=@id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="id" PropertyName="Text" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="loc" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and cs code here

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string qry = "insert into location (loc)values(@loc) ";
    SqlConnection con = Connection.Getconnection();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", TextBox1.Text);
    int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (x > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation!", "<script>alert('Successfully Add')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation!", "<script>alert('Error')</script>");
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Apply validation group on Add location textbox.

Comment: @Webruster not getting error but unable to update my items in gridview

Comment: @KKZone post your code.. did you used `try catch` to catch hold of exception?

Comment: What happens when you click edit. Do you postback or just make the current field editable using **RowEditing** method?

Comment: @KKZone, Put your Add location text box and all button code here.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal yes when i edit in gridview then page postback occur

Comment: check proper validation group and causevalidattion true or false

Comment: If you are calling **RowEditing** event then you can disable the required field validator e.g. RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false; and after updating data in **RowUpdating** you can again enable the validator.

Comment: @Webruster code added

Comment: @KKZone  Cs code behind ?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal i'm using `SqlDataSource` update command

Comment: @Webruster cs code added

Comment: @KaushikMaheta  already Applied  validation group on Add location textbox

Comment: @KKZone you didnt added `try catch` for `button1_click`. 2.validation group  has an effect only when the value of the `CausesValidation property` is set to true.and validation group need to specify a `value` .[Check this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KKZone did that work?

Comment: @Webruster yes, i make validation group for all control, now it's working

Comment: @KKZone Posted this as answer can you mark it as answer for future reference for users coming from google!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please try to  add `try catch` for button1_click to catch Exceptions.
2. Validation group has an effect only when the value of the CausesValidation property is set to true.and validation group need to specify a `value` 
   Please Refer this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @kkzone can i know the reason for not accepting it as answer even after solving your problem ?